# Where would errors be logged/displayed if I'm having connection errors when connecting to Oracle from Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA + Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This perhaps could be attached to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164966/connecting-spring-boot-to-oracle-what-am-i-missing), but it is indeed a different question.

I'm not sure where to look for notice of connection or SQL errors when using Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA + Hibernate to connect to Oracle. I see no error messages on the terminal. I'm not finding a log file. Where should I look?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Here's my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myserver.mycompany.com:1521/MYDBNAME
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
#hibernate config
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Comment: Can you post your application.properties and any other configs that you have for the logging?

Comment: @aksappy, I've edited to show the file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: By default, INFO logging enabled for the whole application, in the terminal. Are you seeing them at least?

Comment: Yes, INFO logging is happening. Do I need to configure a more detailed level of logging to see these errors?

Comment: INFO logs will print the ERROR ones as well. You can add `debug=true` into the application.properties and it will print all possible logs. See this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#core-properties